# Upgrading Spring boot to 2.4.X with Apache Camel 2.X.X

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

We are using Java 1.8, Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE with Camel 2.17.1. As this is a very old release now, the team wants to upgrade to latest Spring Boot (2.4.X) and Camel (3.4.2), but due to some deadline issues we can afford only upgrade Spring Boot right now.

As this link, [start.io](https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/blob/master/start-site/src/main/resources/application.yml#:%7E:text=name:%20Apache%20Camel), it gives the information about the compatible ranges of Spring Boot with Camel for only Camel version 3.X.X onward.

Can Spring Boot 2.4.X be used with Camel 2.17.1 or must both frameworks be upgraded simultaneously?

Comment: No. As it depends on an older version of spring this will inevitably lead to weird issues (classes not found, abstract method errors etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Camel version that is released is only supporting the version of Spring Boot it was built against, e.g., Camel 2.25.x that would be Spring Boot 2.1.x.

There isn't any plan upstream to release a new Camel 2.x release supporting Spring Boot 2.4 or later. Camel 2.x will be [EOL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/EOL#Noun) at the end of this year, and currently it's not actively developed. We only fix critical bugs and security issues that affect Camel source code (not third parties).

However, Red Hat Integration (commercial product) will, in its next upcoming release, support Spring Boot 2.4.x and also Java 11. That is a special effort they have done to their product (not upstream). As Red Hat is actively supporting their customers for a longer period, than what is possible to do *for free* at Apache Software Foundation.